# Javascript Dates - Removing Timezone Information

Tags: node.js, date, momentjs

I have a web application where my users are in NYC but admins are spread across the world. The use case is simple. Admins click on a date and add some notes. Users when they log in to the app , click on the same date and sees the note

Problem is timezone. When an Admin from India adds data on January 1 2019 his data is getting added to Dec 31 2018 as the server is converting the incoming IST to EST. This is breaking the application.

I cant handle individual timezone. So I want to ensure that the frontend is always passing the date in EST irrespective of the local timezone

```
 private normalizeDate(d)
{
    let noTime = moment(d).format("L");
    let m = moment(noTime).tz("America/New_York");
    alert("no time :"+noTime);
    alert("normalized :"+m.format("L"));
}
```

I tried this function where i get the date in local timezone (d) and remove all information. Convert into a string and then parse it back to my EST timezone.

Evidently whenever I call . moment().tz() it is converting the timezone again.

Any idea what is the best solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used this to resolve the problem

```
    public static NormalizeDate(d, timezone = "America/New_York")
    {
        var a = moment(d);
        var b = a.clone();
        return b.tz(timezone, true).startOf("day"); 
    }
```